# Careers always reports "Last seen on Stack Overflow yesterday" in the US evenings

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, time, timezone

It would appear that in the US evening time, the *careers* web-site always reports that a person was last seen yesterday (*Last seen on Stack Overflow yesterday*), even if the Stack Overflow profile itself reports that the person was *Last seen* a few seconds or minutes ago.

Unless time travel is officially supported by Careers, it appears to be a bug, and is probably timezone-related.

If anything, I would think that the correct behaviour would be to always report *today*, unless more than 24h have elapsed since the last visit.

Comment: Stack Overflow times are always based on midnight UTC. So "yesterday" is technically accurate

Comment: @psubsee2003, then it's the other way around, actually -- i think the time actually becomes "tomorrow", yet wraps around and gets reported as "yesterday".

Comment: Still, the user profile and careers should display time in the same way.

Comment: @psubsee2003, so, to confirm my comment as above, I did a little script -- I can confirm that it only says "yesterday" between 20:00 PT and 23:59 PT, and switches back to "today" at midnight PT, without the user being online!  So, it's indeed an overflow, and is indeed supposed to say "tomorrow" if it was coded "correctly"! :-)

Comment: @MathiasMüller, no, the careers profile is supposed to be more like a resume, and those are generally printed on trees, and filed away by the HR as permanent records; there'd be little value to the exact number of seconds the user was last seen at.

Comment: But you don't want Careers to have "yesterday" when your profile has "today" - which is what I meant, but my writing was imprecise.